# Odoo installation error: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "ir_module_module" does not exist

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I want to install Odoo version 12 on my "Windows Server 2019" with "Python 3.9" and "postgresql 13" but when I want to create DB this error is shown:

```
Database creation error: relation "ir_model" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT * FROM ir_model WHERE state='manual' ^
```

I used this command to run Odoo:

```
python odoo-bin -r user -w pass -d odoo -i base --db-filter=^%d$
```

When I checked pgAdmin Odoo had made the DB but there is no table stored in there.

Comment: Have you followed the steps from [this tutorial](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/setup/install.html) ? It is the official page which defines steps to do to deploy [Odoo](https://www.odoo.com/).